# Can Oracle Coherence support complex queries like MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, oracle-coherence

In Mongodb, you can write queries that include multiple attributes of objects and even nested objects. Does oracle coherence support such complex queries or is it a simple K/V store?

Sample Mongodb query:

```
db.reports.find({profit:{$gt:99}, classification:'gas', name:/^USA/})
```

Is it possible to do similar queries on coherence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can query entries **belonging to a single cache** against multiple object attributes (nested objects included).
You can either use [Filter API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22837/api_querycache.htm#BABBABHE) or [Coherence Query Language](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22837/api_cq.htm#CDDIBCDH) to do that.

The above query expressed via Filters would be something like:

```
reportsCache.entrySet(new AllFilter(new Filter[] {
                    new GreaterFilter("getProfit", 99),
                    new EqualsFilter("getClassification", "gas"),
                    new LikeFilter("getName", "USA%")
            }));
```

or using CohQL:

```
select * from "reports" where profit > 99 and classification = "gas" and name like "USA%"
```